# Has anyone discovered this Collatz Conjecture pattern?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

I noticed that there is a linear increase of +1 in the stopping times of a sequence of numbers with the seeds being the sum of the previous number in the sequence added to itself.

I tried this on Excel. The hailstone sequences converge to 1, as expected.

[image: for a sequence starting with 3]

I also tried it with different numbers as the starting point (ex. 5 10 20 40...)

Does this have any significance?

Comment: That’s just the fact that the stopping time of $2n$ is one plus the stopping time of $n$, no?

Comment: Please use embedded ASCII instead of images.

Comment: Do you mean that every new record (in the number of steps) is only one better than the current record ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I mean either. hehe

Comment: The depth in which the Collatz conjecture has been studied is unimaginable. Small start values exhibit some notable patterns which have almost surely be detected by someone which does not mean that this observation was also published. Unfortunately, all patterns eventually vanish because of the dynamic of the sequence. A proof of this conjecture in , say , the next $20$ years would be more than sensational.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very trivial observation. If the stopping time of a number $x$ is $n$, then the stopping time for the double of $x$: $2x$ is $n + 1$ because it takes one step for $2x$ to drop down to $x$ by division of 2.

Comment: hmmm does this mean that since all natural numbers follow this observation, that the collatz conjecture is true?

Comment: or that you only need to prove that the conjecture is true for odd and prime numbers, to prove that the conjecture is true for all natural numbers?

Comment: If you prove the conjecture true for odd numbers, then it's true for all numbers

Comment: @PassylA it means that if you first prove that all odd numbers $x$ terminate, you have proven that all even numbers of the form $2^nx$ also terminate. But to prove the conjecture, you must first prove every odd number terminates.